# Making a help dialog display a command tree

Tags: c#

So I am making a console application and I want to make a command tree type of thing like this:

```
    Help:
    Example Text
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |---Example Text
```

But, I don't want it to have all those spaces.
I have tried using this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Example Command");
    Console.WriteLine("|");
    Console.WriteLine("|");
    Console.WriteLine("|");
    Console.WriteLine("|");
    Console.WriteLine("|---Example Text");
```

I just don't know how to remove the spaces. Is there some kind of formatting thing that makes all the text super close together. The reason I say this is because in a command prompt they have this in one of the commands and there is no space between the dashes.

Comment: Please provide more details. What have you tried? What is your end goal? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks! I am kinda new to stackoverflow.

Comment: We have no idea how you're trying to produce that output, or where "all those spaces" are or how they're getting there in the first place. You're going to need to be much more specific with your question. Please [edit] to do so, and remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind when you do. The only information we have about your question is *exactly what you tell us*. If you want us to help, you have to give us the details so we can try and do so.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will include a picture pointing out where the spaces exactly are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters

You want to use the appropriate characters for drawing lines. A pipe and dash are made to have a gap based on the font.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. That works perfectly. I didn't realize that there were different characters for drawing lines. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided in TyCobb's answer, if you want an example,

```
char horizontal = '\u2550';
char vertical = '\u2501';
char vertJunction = '\u2560';

string horiz = horizontal.ToString();
string vert = vertical.ToString();
string vertJ = vertJunction.ToString();
```

You can then use `horiz`, `vert`, and `vertJ` (or whatever you choose to call them) together to draw in your program.